# Cannot resolve symbol 'JobIntentService'

Tags: android, android-studio, jobintentservice

I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/08/27/custom-gboard-sticker-pack/

However I am failing at Step 3, because I cannot extend my subclass from `JobIntentService`. I get the Error Message `Cannot resolve symbol 'JobIntentService'`. I found people getting similar error messages, but I couldn't follow their solutions, as it expected prerequisite knowledge I don't have. All I ever did in Android Programming is the steps in the tutorial.

Comment: `JobIntentService` in general was [deprecated almost 2 years ago](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#1.6.0-rc01). I'd suggest trying a more recent tutorial that is up to date.

Comment: @ianhanniballake the issue is is that the most recent tutorial i can find is half a year old and runs into the exact same issue